# Task<List<<anonymous type>>>' does not contain a definition for 'First'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have a general configuration table where settings are stored as string records. Table has <5 records. I need to return data from this table into a json result
  I've done this way

```
 return Ok(new
            {
                SNAME = db.PAR.First(p => p.ID == 1).VAL.Trim(),
                PART = db.PAR.First(p => p.ID == 2).VAL.Trim(),
                NRZMAXEDIT = db.PAR.First(p => p.ID == 3).VAL,
            .......
        });
```

the code could be improved, so I've rewritten it to:

```
  var res = db.PAR.ToList();

    return Ok(new
            {   SNAME = res.First(p => p.ID == 1).VAL,
                PART =res.First(p => p.ID == 2).VAL,
                NRZMAXEDIT = res.First(p => p.ID == 3).VAL,
                  ....
        });
```

It works but if I use async    `var res = db.PAR.ToListAsync();`, I am getting an error:

> `Task<List<<anonymous type: int ID, string VAL>>>` does not contain a
>   definition for `First` and no extension method `First`        accepting a 
>   first argument of type `Task<List<<anonymous type: int ID, string VAL>>>` could be found          (are you missing a using directive or an 
>   assembly reference?)

on every line where I use query like that:

```
res.First(p => p.ID == 1).VAL,
```

thanks

Comment: You forgot `await` keyword:
`var res = await db.PAR.ToListAsync();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `await` keyword before `db.PAR.ToListAsync()` like below.

```
var res = await db.PAR.ToListAsync();
```

**Note:** The return type of `ToListAsync()` is `Task<List<TSource>>`